# Remove all spaces and combine multiple lines to single line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What is the best way to remove all spaces from a string in SQL Server 2014?

My string is:

```
Maximize your productivity for building engaging,

 beautiful web mapping applications
```

Trying to remove enter and tab spaces between string and 1 space between words. Result should be like:

```
Maximize your productivity for building engaging, beautiful web mapping applications
```

Comment: This is a good candidate for a reusable user-defined function.

Comment: See updated answer.  I removed 32.  It was not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If open to a UDF, the following will remove all control characters and repeating spaces.

The removal of the repeating spaces was inspired (*OK stolen*) from **Gordon's** answer a few months ago.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Maximize your productivity for building engaging,

 beautiful web mapping applications'


Select [dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control](@S)
```

Returns

```
Maximize your productivity for building engaging, beautiful web mapping applications
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Select @S=Replace(@S,char(n),' ')
     From  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31) ) N(n)

    Return LTrim(RTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(@S,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')))
End
--Select [dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael        '+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')  --Returns: Michael LastName
```

Comment: Removed the value  (32)... was not needed / redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace()`, but it is a bit tricky:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', '<>'
                                              ), '
', '<>'
                                      ), ' ', '<>'  -- tab goes here
                              ), '><', ''
                       ), '<>', ' '
               )
from t;
```

The idea is that a space is replaced with `<>`, then all `><`s are removed leaving only one.  For instance:

```
a    b c     -- original data with three spaces and one space
a<><><>b<>c  -- after replacing spaces with <>
a<>b<>c      -- after removing ><
a b c        -- after replacing <> with a space
```

Comment: it works for for example X Enter y string, but for X enter Y enter Z is not working