# TSQL - Remove list of parameters from Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a field in a SQL table which has text looks something like this:

```
'The Employee <PARAM1> was replaced with <PARAM2> and was given the new IP address <PARAM3> with limited access <PARAM4>. <PARAM2> loves the new role'
```

I want to remove all the `<PARAMs>` from the text and just show as below using TSQL

```
'The Employee was replaced with and was given the new IP address with limited access. loves the new role'
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: both statements seem identical. Not sure what you want to do here... to replace text, look at the REPLACE function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: @SQLRaptor they aren't - there is some text being hidden.  I'm not sure you have an edit link where you can see it, but if not, an edited post should appear soon.

Comment: You need to be more explicit about the question, the only difference seems to be a space missing between the `.` and the end of the sentence.  Will you edit and clarify exactly what it is you are try to accomplish?

Comment: Not sure why it happened when I posted the question. I wanted to put the question as below.


I have a field in a SQL table which has text looks something like below.

'The <PARAM1> was replaced with <PARAM2> and was given the new IP address with limited <PARAM3> . <PARAM1> loves the new role'

I want to remove all the from the <PARAMs> text and just show as below using TSQL

'The Employee was replaced with Manager and was given the new IP address with limited access. Employee loves the new role'

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Use the [REPLACE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp) function of SQL click the link and read how it works.

Comment: Simple REPLACE() function will not work. What text value I should replace? Should I replace '<PARAM1>' or '<PARAM2>' or so on.

Comment: what's the maximum number of PARAM values that you would have?  What version of SQL server are you on?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to generate a common table expression that will hold the start position and length of each `<PARAMn>` in the string. To do that, you can use a single common table expression but I've done it with three so that the process is easy to understand.
Please note that I'm assuming the string only contains `<` and `>` as params separators - so there is no `<` or `>` chars in the content. If that's not the case, it's still solvable but the solution would need some changes.

You start with a numbers (tally) cte that starts with 1 and ends with the length of your string.
Then another cte to get the start position of each `<PARAMn>`.
A third cte is used to get the length of each `<PARAMn>` (since I'm assuming you are not limited to 10 parameters in a string, so you can have `<PARAM12>` or even `<PARAM105>`).

Then, create a query that will update the original string and remove the `<PARAMn>` one by one.

```
-- Test data:
DECLARE @str nvarchar(1000) = 'The Employee <PARAM1> was replaced with <PARAM2> and was given the new IP address <PARAM3> with limited access <PARAM4>. <PARAM2> loves the new role';

-- The numbers (Tally) cte:
WITH Tally AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@Str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N
    FROM sys.objects A CROSS JOIN sys.objects B
), -- The StartPosition cte contains the position of each < char in the string
StartPosition AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
        CHARINDEX('<', @Str, N) As Start
FROM Tally
WHERE CHARINDEX('<', @Str, N) > 0

), -- the Length cte contains both the start position and the length of each <PARAMn> in the string
Length As
(
    SELECT  Start,
            CHARINDEX('>', @Str, Start) - Start + 1 As Length
    FROM StartPosition
)

-- Use STUFF to remove `<PARAMn>`. Note the order by is critical to remove from end to start.
SELECT @Str = STUFF(@Str, Start, Length, '')
FROM Length
ORDER BY Start DESC

-- verify the results:
SELECT @Str
```

Result:

```
The Employee  was replaced with  and was given the new IP address  with limited access .  loves the new role
```

You might note that the results have places with double spaces where the `<PARAMn>` used to be - that can be solved by using the technique Gordon Linoff shows in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225264/3094533)